# relation between a square matrix and inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

i have two claims i need to check and i'm not sure about.

claims are:

a)if a square matrix $A$ zeros(annihilates) the polynom$p(t)=t^2+5t+1$ then $A$ is invertible$

b)if a square matrix $A$ zeros(annihilates) the polynom$p(t)=t^{102}+t^2+t$ then $A$ is invertible

what i think:

a)not true, because for the matrix to be invertible,  The equation $Ax=0$ has to have only the trivial solution $x=0$.

b)true, because in this case only x=0 zeros the matrix.

and a small question if i may, i saw a question that happens to be very simple and i'm wondering if it is that simple or a trick question(claim) i don't understand: $A=diag{0,0,0,0,0,0}$ then A zeros(annihilates) the polynom $t^6-t$. seems to be obviously true according to Cayley–Hamilton theorem. is it that simple or am i missing something?

thank you very much for your help.

Comment: In regards to Cayley-Hamilton, don't confuse *minimal* or *characteristic* polynomials with arbitrary polynomials.

Comment: @JMoravitzthank you for correcting me. i'm wondering, does the last claim regarding $A=diag{0,0,0,0,0,0}$ zeros(annihilates) the polynom$t^6-t$, is it correct like it seems or is it a false claim?

Comment: Yes, $A^6-A=0$ where $A=0$.  So too does $A=diag[\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3,\phi_4,\phi_5,0]$ satisfy $A^6-A=0$ where $\phi_1,\dots,\phi_5$ are the five fifth-roots of $1$ (*which actually has $t^6-t$ as its characteristic polynomial*).  So too does $A=I$ annihilate the polynomial. The point is that $t^6-t$ is not the characteristic polynomial of $I$, but it is a multiple of the characteristic polynomial of $I$ which is $t-1$.  Specifically, $t^6-t=\color{blue}{(t-1)}(t(t^4+t^3+t^2+t+1))$.  A matrix will annihilate its characteristic polynomial **and** any multiple of it's characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually:

a) It's true, because $A^5+5A+\operatorname{Id}=0$ and therefore $A(-A^4-5\operatorname{Id})=\operatorname{Id}$.

b) Not true. The null matrix annihilates the polynomial.

Comment: could you please explain to me how you got: $A(-A^4-5\operatorname{Id})=\operatorname{Id}$? sorry but i don't understand

Comment: $$\begin{align}A^5+5A+\operatorname{Id}=0&\iff-A^5-5A=\operatorname{Id}\\&\iff A(-A^4-5\operatorname{Id})=\operatorname{Id}.\end{align}$$

Comment: thank you very much. it's much clearer now